# Carriage return and line feeds in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I'm using the following SQL to display date/time information.

```
+ 'DateM (Monday): ' + ISNULL(@Mon,'')+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
+ 'DateT (Tuesday): ' + ISNULL(@Tues,'')+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
```

There is no wrapping in between the dates.

`DateM (Monday): Sep  8 2009 12:00AM DateT(Tuesday): Sep  9 2009 12:00AM`

I want it to wrap like below:

```
DateM (Monday): Sep  8 2009 12:00AM 
DateT(Tuesday): Sep  9 2009 12:00AM
```

How can I modify the SQL so that the dates will wrap?

Comment: Where do you print your output? You use PRINT function?

Comment: I can guess that the problem is not on the db side. If you send an email in HTML format you have to break lines using '<br />'. Try this.

Comment: @Lukasz where do I need to put '<br />'?

Comment: 'DateM (Monday): ' + ISNULL(@Mon,'')+ '<br />'

It is only quess. I had a similar problem with MySQL and PHP.

Comment: :( I tried that it didn't work :( any solution ppl?

Comment: @Lukasz what I did is added another +CHAR(13), it wrapped but it gives me double space.

Comment: This works:

'DateT (Tuesday): ' + ISNULL(CONVERT (VARCHAR(8),@Tues,1),'')+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)

Answer (score 0):

This works:

'DateT (Tuesday): ' + ISNULL(CONVERT (VARCHAR(8),@Tues,1),'')+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)